# Spring Boot - RestController different error handler for different paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot service. It has /api/v1 path, now I add /api/v2 path for a new api. 
But errors/exceptions in v2 have different return values etc. So is it possible for each RestController to create two different exception handlers for different paths?

Comment: Put them in different classes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as Kayaman suggested, try to handle two differenct exception classes (v1/ v2)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(V1Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(V1Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(gson.toJson("[v1]" + ex.getMessage()));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(V2Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(V2Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(gson.toJson("[v2]" + ex.getMessage()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible for each RestController to create two different exception handlers for different paths?

Yes, you can use different `@ControllerAdvice`s and declare your `@ExceptionHandler`s in them. But you have to tell the framework which controllers should particular `@ControllerAdvice` assist

There are different ways to do it. Check out [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) parameters:

- basePackages / basePackageClasses if your v1 and v2 Controllers are in different packages.
- annotations. You need to create some custom annotation for v1 controllers and v2 controllers.
- assignableTypes.